# Position a div within childs of a sibling div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is inserted by a library. Basically this div contains 2 child divs with unknown height which can change depending on API response and browser window width.

I want to show my div (`my-div`) between `top-bar` and `bottom-bar`

```html
<div class="my-div">
  My content with known height 
</div>

<div class="library-output">
  <div class="top-bar">Some content goes here with unknown height</div>
  <div class="bottom-bar">Another content goes here with unknown height</div>
</div>
```

I can not modify the library nor modify its output with js (basically library is a react app which is downloaded from a 3rd party web-site). Class names of all divs are known in advance.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS? I am thinking about applying margin-bottom to `top-bar` so there will be enough space but I am struggling with positioning of `my-div`,

Comment: Without JavaScript on this one you're going to be fighting an uphill battle

Comment: @j08691 I can run any js code, it is not a problem. I just can not mess with DOM inside of `div.library-output`

Comment: So what have you tried in JS then?

Answer (score 0):

In general to insert an element after another element with Javascript you can use this pattern 
`someElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, someElement.nextSibling);`

Where newElement is the element to be inserted and someElement is the element it is to be inserted after.

So in your case that would look like:

`const myDiv = document. getElementsByClassName( 'my-div' );
const topDiv = document. getElementsByClassName( 'top-bar' );
topDiv.parentNode.insertBefore( myDiv, topDiv.nextSibling );`